# Automatic log in to Neo4j on page render

Tags: python, django, authentication, neo4j

I have Neo4j 3.5.7 Community Edition installed on a server, which will be used for demo purposes. I also have a Django front end. Since Neo4jCE doesn't allow to remove authentication, I would like to automatically log in when rendering the Neo4j browser page.

In Django's settings.py I use a bolt URL that has the URL of the DB, the username and password, but when the Neo4j browser page is displayed, the log in form appears, populated with the URL and username.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you want to automatically log in, or do you want to prevent the login UI, or something else?

Comment: By logging in automatically the login UI won't be displayed. So I would say I would like to log in automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the authentification on the CE of Neo4j.
You just have to add the folliwing line in the `neo4j.conf` file :

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```